# Recurrence Relation on Stirling Numbers of the First Kind

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, generating-functions, stirling-numbers

I've been playing around with Stirling Numbers and have stumbled upon the following relation which I think is true (I've tested for $n=3,4,5,6$). I can't seem to prove this however, and was wondering how one could prove the following equality.

Let $\begin{bmatrix}n \\ k\end{bmatrix}$ denote the Stirling number of the first kind for $n$ elements and $k$ cycles. Prove that $$\begin{bmatrix}n+1 \\ 2\end{bmatrix}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}k\begin{bmatrix}n \\ k\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: you can use induction instead